# Animating Monte Carlo Method Pi color dots diferently

Tags: python, matplotlib, colors, matplotlib-animation

I want to have an animation of my plot of my results of the mc method calculating pi; but having the inner circle dots colored differently than the others. How can I do that?
This is my code so far:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from matplotlib.animation import FuncAnimation

def punkt_im_quadrat(a,N): #a is length of square, N number of dots
"""generates random point in [0,a)x[0,a)"""
    x = a * np.random.random_sample((N,2))
    return x #[x,y]

def kreis(radius):
    return np.sqrt(radius - x**2)
x = np.linspace(0,1,100)

#create array of N=10 dots
punkte = punkt_im_quadrat(1,10) #a=1, so radius of circle is one


treffer = [i for i in punkte if i[1] <= np.sqrt(1 - i[0]**2)] #dots in circle
treffer = np.array(treffer)

außerhalb = [i for i in punkte if i not in treffer] #dots not in circle
außerhalb = np.array(außerhalb)


pi = 4 * len(treffer) / np.shape(punkte)[0] 

fig = plt.figure()
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.plot(x,kreis(1))
ax.set_xlim(0,1)
ax.set_ylim(0,1)
ax.set(title=r"MC Sampling for $\pi$", 
      ylabel="y-axis",
      xlabel="x-axis")
#colors = ["r" if [punkte[i][0],punkte[i][1]] in treffer else "b"]
graph, = ax.plot([],[], "ro")

def animate(i):
    graph.set_data((punkte[:i,0],), (punkte[:i,1],))
    return graph,


animation = FuncAnimation(fig, func=animate, frames = range(np.shape(punkte)[0]), interval=20, repeat = False)
plt.show()
```

As you can see, I have tried to change the colors by using the commented color if statement; but it then says 
IndexError: arrays used as indices must be of integer (or boolean) type

I then thought I could do an if statement in the animated-function, to determine where the dot is. But when using `graph.set_color` it changes all dots color.

I'd be really happy if someone can help me.
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All the markers in a `plot` have the same color, so that cannot work. If you want different colors for different points, you need to use `scatter()`

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from matplotlib.animation import FuncAnimation

def punkt_im_quadrat(a,N): #a is length of square, N number of dots
    """generates random point in [0,a)x[0,a)"""
    x = a * np.random.random_sample((N,2))
    return x #[x,y]

def kreis(radius):
    return np.sqrt(radius - x**2)
x = np.linspace(0,1,100)

#create array of N=10 dots
punkte = punkt_im_quadrat(1,10) #a=1, so radius of circle is one


treffer = [i for i in punkte if i[1] <= np.sqrt(1 - i[0]**2)] #dots in circle
treffer = np.array(treffer)

außerhalb = [i for i in punkte if i not in treffer] #dots not in circle
außerhalb = np.array(außerhalb)

colors = np.array(["r" if i[1] <= np.sqrt(1 - i[0]**2) else "b" for i in punkte])


pi = 4 * len(treffer) / np.shape(punkte)[0] 

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.plot(x,kreis(1))
ax.set_xlim(0,1)
ax.set_ylim(0,1)
ax.set(title=r"MC Sampling for $\pi$", 
      ylabel="y-axis",
      xlabel="x-axis")
graph = ax.scatter([],[], marker='o', s=30)

def animate(i):
    graph.set_offsets(punkte[:i,:])
    graph.set_facecolor(colors[:i])
    return graph,


animation = FuncAnimation(fig, func=animate, frames = range(np.shape(punkte)[0]), interval=20, repeat = False)
```

Comment: Thank you very much! I think I don't understand what s=30 and set_offsets does.. (it's hard learning to read the documentation)

Comment: `s=30` defines the size of the points, as per [the documentation](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.scatter.html?highlight=scatter#matplotlib.axes.Axes.scatter), `set_offsets()` changes the coordinates of the points, eq. to `set_data()` in your code